# Split select results

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have next query:

```
SELECT login_id
FROM invite
WHERE sender_id in (111, 222) AND is_valid IS TRUE
```

and result is next:

```
login_id
4205
4154
9
```

What I need us to split 'login_id' to related 'sender_id'.
In my case result should be next:

```
111    222
4205   9
4154
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use conditional aggregation - but you need a column to aggregate by.  You can get that using `ROW_NUMBER()`:

```
SELECT MAX(login_id) FILTER (WHERE sender_id = 111) as sender_111,
       MAX(login_id) FILTER (WHERE sender_id = 222) as sender_222       
FROM (SELECT i.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY sender_id ORDER BY sender_id) as seqnum
      FROM invite i
     ) i
WHERE sender_id in (111, 222) AND is_valid IS TRUE
GROUP BY seqnum;
```

Note:  You might find it more convenient to return the results in a single row as arrays:

```
select array_agg(login_id) filter (where sender_id = 111) as sender_111,
       array_agg(login_id) filter (where sender_id = 222) as sender_222
from invite i
where sender_id in (111, 222) and is_valid;
```